# rpart plot returns only 2 classes (not entire plot)

Tags: r, r-caret

I have this data (in reality it contains some thousand rows and more names/classes):

```
A  0.5  0.2  T
B  0.4  0.2  T
C  0.6  0.3  F
D  0.5  0.4  G
E  0.4  0.5  F
E  0.5  0.2  Y
A  0.1  0.2  F
R  0.3  0.3  G
W  0.7  0.1  Y
```

I want to predict the last column.

My code:

```
library(caret)
library(rpart.plot)


mydata <- read.table("./test.data", dec = "\t")
mydata <- as.data.frame(mydata)

colnames(mydata) <- c("Name", "V1", "V2", "Result")

trainIndex <- createDataPartition(mydata$Result, p = 0.7, list = FALSE, times = 1)
train_data <- mydata[trainIndex, ]
test_data <- mydata[-trainIndex, ]

trctrl <- trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", repeats = 1, number = 3)

mymodel <- train(Result~., data = train_data, method = "rpart", trControl = trctrl)

rpart.plot(mymodel$finalModel)
```

The problem is that the plot shows only 1 variable instead of all
(of course now the problem is trivial but in my real problem where I have many rows and 10 different classes to select, it shows me the decision tree with only 2 classes)

[image]

Comment: if I understand what youre asking, there is only need to show one since you have one node which has F as the largest proportion. in your actual plot, I assume there are only two types which dominate every node

Comment: @rawr:Hmm, but shouldn't the plot give me all the "range"?

Comment: @rawr:Also, if in the above dataset , I insert more lines and have 3 classes with each one of (F,G,Y,T), it still gives me only the F.

Comment: I'm not sure; you can always add a full legend yourself. You've increased the classes equally so there is still more F than the others

Comment: @raw:I am sorry, I didn't quite understand what you said `add a full legend yourself.`Also, why is still more F than the others since there are same number of classes?Generally, do you believe that the code is right?And that in my original problem where I have 10 classes and receive only 2 on the plot, is correct?Thanks

Comment: there are 3/9 Fs = 0.33333; there are 2/9 Gs = 0.22222; there are 2/9 Ts = 0.22222; and there are 2/9 Ys = 0.22222. The single parent node contains all the data because this is what you start with. The Fs dominate the node, so the color is green. There are no other nodes which are dominated by another type, so another color in the legend is not needed

Comment: the default colors will be the same, you can change them, a full legend can be `legend('topleft', bty = 'n', border = NA, fill = sapply(list(rpart.plot:::Greens, rpart.plot:::Blues, rpart.plot:::Grays, rpart.plot:::Oranges, rpart.plot:::Reds), '[', 9L), c('F', 'G', 'T', 'Y'), xpd = NA)`

Comment: @rawr:ok, thanks but as I told you I changed the data in order to contain 3 Fs, 3Gs, 3Ts, 3Ys, all equal and still gives me only F.